# Monitor doesn't switch source while PC is connected

Tags: graphics-card, display, hdmi

I have an *Acer S243HL* PC monitor with multiple inputs. As long as my PC is plugged in via HDMI, I can't switch to any other source without it immediately snapping back to the PC HDMI source.

I know that HDMI has the capability to "demand focus" from a TV or Monitor, and I suppose that feature is the problem. Even if another HDMI device is connected to the monitor, my PC will always override it and not allow any sort of source switching of the monitor, it always instantly snaps back to HDMI1 (or HDMI2, depending on where I plug in the PC).

My PC is running Windows 7, and the GPU is the AMD R9 290. From what I've read, almost no GPUs, at least not professional grade ones, have HDMI-CEC, and I've found no option to disable it either in the drivers yet.

Comment: in case its a monitor quirk, what's your monitor model?

Comment: It's the Acer S243HL